# Нужна помощь по Selenium на C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Имеется следующая задача по написанию автотеста на C#:
необходимо перейти по ссылке, в открывшейся странице сгенерировать 5 раз персональный идентификационный номер. В каждом сгенерированном номере необходимо проверить на чётность/нечётность последнюю цифру, и соответственно вывести на консоль результат - чётный или нет.
Реализовал я это следующим образом:

```
private static void Main()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://generatory.it/");

            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                IWebElement generateNewPesel = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@onclick = 'setGeneratedPesel()']"));
                generateNewPesel.Click();

                string Pesel = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id = 'peselBox']")).Text;

                char[] peselArray = Pesel.ToCharArray();

                if (peselArray[10] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The element is even");
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The element is odd");
                    count++;
                }                
            } while (count <= 4);
```

В дополнение к вышеописанному заданию необходимо добавить в код сравнение - отличается ли каждый новый сгенерированный номер от предыдущего.
И вот с этим сранением у меня тупик.
Теоретически я мог бы каждый сгенерированный номер записывать в отдельную переменную и затем просто сранивать, например при помощи метода string.Compare, но как по мне это получится слишком много строчек кода и будет это всё выглядеть нелаконично.

Знающие, подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли к уже написанному мной коду прилепить сравнение в каждой итерации?
Ну или как-то по другому.
Заранее благодарен всем откликнувшимся.

Comment: Создайте коллекцию, запишите туда требуемые элементы, потом хоть на ноль их делите. Задача дошкольного уровня. Циклы и массивы, массивы и циклы, первые несколько страниц любого учебника по шарпу почитать.

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам тут нужен целый браузер, для простой генерации? Логика генерации значений там [открыта](http://generatory.it/js/pesel-utils.js), переписать на C# думаю легко будет. Ну а если надо прям с сервера логику брать, то почему бы не использовать просто один из движков JS, в который подкините скрипт и запустите сразу нужную функцию, например [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ выглядит как учебное задание на селениуме

Comment: @aepot Довольно странное задание, которое толком ничему не научит, а наоборот, даст человеку "палочку выручалочку", которую он потом будет везде воспринимать как единственное верное решение, не разбираясь, как и что устроено. Я понял бы еще, если тут тестировался бы UI, ок, зашли, проверили, понажимали кнопочки, но логику.... Хоть убейте, не пойму)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ из чудо-писателей мало кто до настоящего прода добирается. Так, фриланс на недельку за 3 рубля максимум. Оно почти всё разовое, и вопросов зачастую о том, как писать хороший код и какие правильные инструменты использовать, не возникает. Что нашли в ютубе, то и пишут. Понастоящему шарят в сетевых технологиях немногие. Была мысль запилить свой блог-записнушку по десктопам, но в феврале передумал. Недостаток материалов на русском сказывается в целом на атмосфере дотнет-разработки.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ была еще мысль пару хабров по WinUI3 запилить, но оно пока настолько сырое, что я подожду.

Comment: @aepot Вот плохо, что не хотят разбираться как правильно, и плохо, что на такие вопросы дается ответ все теми же костылями, без какого-либо упоминания правильного подхода. Вот реально, опускаем тот факт, что это "домашка", нам надо протестировать логику сайта, ну неужели будем тянуть целый браузер ради простой такой задачи? Да нет конечно, но вот кто найдет этот вопрос, опять посчитает это единственным решением) Сколько раз даже мы с вами тут натыкались на вопросы, где люди сразу берут селениум, не разбирая как можно иначе. Обидно, это прям утечка знаний)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если внимательно посмотреть, то этот вопрос похож как раз на тестирование фронта для чайника. А ведь именно для этого и создан селениум. Так как оно завязано на JS, я не стал давать лишних рекомендаций, просто  вопрос-ответ. Если считаете нужным, дополните мой ответ или напишите свой, я только за. )

Comment: @aepot Подход с кликами и прочим да, тест фронта, но остальная логика с четным или нет - это уже обработка полученных данных, а значит основная задача не тест результата с сайта, а своя собственная логика на основе того, что выдал сайт (автоматизация?), а раз идет работа с данными то, как по мне и надо брать сразу данные, минуя UI. Ну а так, это чисто мысли в слух и рассуждение увиденного) По поводу блога - а не поможет, ибо затеряется в тонне мусора. Полезней будет прям тут на SO само-вопрос-ответ писать с нужным материалом, чтоб были в поиске, ну а блог так, для души если.

Comment: Ребят, данное задание я получил от авто-тестеров в своей компании, где я на данный момент работаю как мануальный тестировщик, и самостоятельно изучаю C# в свободное время, всего-то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто получить числа в массив

```
IWebElement generateNewPesel = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@onclick = 'setGeneratedPesel()']"));
IWebElement peselElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("peselBox"));
int[] numbers = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    generateNewPesel.Click();
    numbers[i] = peselElement.Text[^1] - '0'; // получение числа из цифры символа
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numbers));
```

А теперь сравнивайте, проверяйте на четность, что угодно с ними делайте.

Хотя-бы вот четность:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i] % 2 == 0 ? "чётный" : "нечётный");
}
```

> отличается ли каждый новый сгенерированный номер от предыдущего

```
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i] != numbers[i - 1] ? "отличается" : "не отличается");
}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!